# About changing order ID in Opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart-3

Is it possible to make Opencart generate random order id numbers using this format:

`YYMMDD-HHMNSS-ID, WHERE YY=LAST TWO DIGITS OF YEAR, MM=TWO DIGIT MONTH, DD=DAY, HH=HOURS, MN=MINUTES, SS=SECONDS, ID=ORIGINAL ID` eg: 1.

So instead of having let's say an order id of 1, it could be 190704-050610-1?

Comment: No, not possible instead original order_id. Only possible add additional column to order table and than you can generate order number in your style and add to this column. After you can show it where you want.

Comment: Thanks @K.B. can you please guide me as to which codes I have to modify?

Comment: You should add new column  for example `custom_order_id` to your DB `oc_order` table, than edit `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` add to the `public function addOrderHistory(` code which will generate this `custom_order_id` and update the DB table `oc_order` with this new data. Than you can retrieve this `custom_order_id` from your DB where you want.

Answer (score 3):

##### 100% Working in Opencart 3x

[image]

##### ramdom_order_no.ocmod.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
  <code>Random Order Number</code>
  <name>Randomly Order Number Generate Extension</name>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <author>Mujahid Bhoraniya (Email : bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com / Whatsapp : +91 7990167476)</author>
  <link>mujahidbhoraniya</link>
  <!-- =========================================================================
   | Admin All Order Page (Order List, Invoice, Shipping)
   | ======================================================================= -->
  <file path="admin/controller/sale/order.php">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[$results = $this->model_sale_order->getOrders($filter_data);]]></search>
      <add position="after" offset="2"><![CDATA[$order_no = str_replace("-","",$result['date_added']);
            $order_no = str_replace(":","",$order_no);
            $order_no = str_replace(" ","-",$order_no);]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
    <search><![CDATA['customer'      => $result['customer'],]]></search>
      <add position="after"><![CDATA['order_no'      => $order_no."-".$result['order_id'],]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA['invoice_no'       => $invoice_no,]]></search>
      <add position="before" offset="2"><![CDATA[$order_no = str_replace("-","",$order_info['date_added']);
                $order_no = str_replace(":","",$order_no);
                $order_no = str_replace(" ","-",$order_no);]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
    <search><![CDATA['invoice_no'       => $invoice_no,]]></search>
      <add position="after"><![CDATA['order_no'      => $order_no."-".$order_id,]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
    <search><![CDATA[$data['date_added'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added']));]]></search>
      <add position="after"><![CDATA[$order_no = str_replace("-","",$order_info['date_added']);
            $order_no = str_replace(":","",$order_no);
            $order_no = str_replace(" ","-",$order_no);
            $data['order_no'] = $order_no."-".$order_info['order_id'];]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <file path="admin/view/template/sale/order_list.twig">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<td class="text-right">{{ order.order_id }}</td>]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<td class="text-right">{{ order.order_no }}</td>]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <file path="admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.twig">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<h1>{{ text_invoice }} #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<h1>{{ text_invoice }} #{{ order.order_no }}</h1>]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<b>{{ text_order_id }}</b> {{ order.order_id }}<br />]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<b>{{ text_order_id }}</b> {{ order.order_no }}<br />]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <file path="admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.twig">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<h1>{{ text_picklist }} #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<h1>{{ text_picklist }} #{{ order.order_no }}</h1>]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<b>{{ text_order_id }}</b> {{ order.order_id }}<br />]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<b>{{ text_order_id }}</b> {{ order.order_no }}<br />]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <!-- =========================================================================
   | Catalog Order Page (Customer Order List,Customer Invoice/Info)
   | ======================================================================= -->
  <file path="catalog/controller/account/order.php">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[$data['orders'][] = array(]]></search>
      <add position="before"><![CDATA[$order_no = str_replace("-","",$result['date_added']);
            $order_no = str_replace(":","",$order_no);
            $order_no = str_replace(" ","-",$order_no);]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA['order_id'   => $result['order_id'],]]></search>
      <add position="after"><![CDATA['order_no'   => $order_no."-".$result['order_id'],]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[$data['date_added'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added']));]]></search>
      <add position="after"><![CDATA[$order_no = str_replace("-","",$order_info['date_added']);
            $order_no = str_replace(":","",$order_no);
            $order_no = str_replace(" ","-",$order_no);
            
            $data['order_no'] = $order_no."-".$data['order_id'];]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/order_list.twig">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[<td class="text-right">#{{ order.order_id }}</td>]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<td class="text-right">#{{ order.order_no }}</td>]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
  <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/order_info.twig">
    <operation>
      <search><![CDATA[#{{ order_id }}<br />]]></search>
      <add position="replace"><![CDATA[#{{ order_no }}<br />]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
```

**Save** file name to `ramdom_order_no.ocmod.xml`

Then, You can **upload** the `ramdom_order_no.ocmod.xml` **file** in your **system directory** after it's working fine.

**Note:** After uploading the file successfully. Please Clear Cache and Refresh Modification via Admin Panel.

[image]

100% Code working well. you can see my screenshot as well.

Comment: how do use this method to display the order number on the success page?

Comment: hi, Alexander. I am not unable to online on stack every time. your msg seen after 12 hours. if you need any extra customizing you can contact me via WA or Email or linkdin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solution, pls upd end off code with

```
    </file>
</modification>
```

cos you have not closed tag file and modification in the end of code. Some users will get problems

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30862713)

Comment: Em, provided answer is with coding error(not closed code tag), that can cause problem for other peoples when adding code to opencart, sure no need my post. Great Job!